# Remove outlier values from a data.frame using R

Tags: r, outliers

I have a data.frame with columns with water quality values.

I would like to remove the outiliers from each column and in place of the values add nodata NA.

EDIT:

I would like to remove outliers as follows:

Outliers > Quantile 95

and

Outliers < Quantile 5

[image]

how could I do that?

I have an example of my situation

```
df=read.table(text="st  PH  OD  COD N
A   7.3 1.26301094  1.112359589 0.295842925
B   12.69875867 5.670646078 4.841748321 0.096958426
C   9.613564343 1.706277385 7.952266541 0.102672152
D   9.693461149 7.075560183 0.283503075 0.302494648
A   11.2031501  5.444756127 3.133271063 0.421172108
B   9.288552402 4.169068095 10.54049312 0.122900615
C   4.207333379 6.717653051 10.49073885 0.085634135
D   10.98593946 2.352068972 8.468436777 0.142284793
A   8.20679887  7.826764274 4.464242367 0.211200956
B   12.9165421  0.909886436 1.488358471 0.001640961
C   3.971088246 8.500668307 6.315208679 0.319835127
D   4.821068685 3.871082236 8.669284239 0.349317325
A   0.431563127 0.978922921 10.53756208 0.111929377
B   7.546887828 9.946840115 1.584013576 0.426681716
C   4.689617182 8.717656795 7.474709944 0.473463497
D   9.730568456 1.134763618 4.679810195 0.215744107
A   12.06381259 6.862549062 0.559497593 0.231984105
", 
sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: It all depends on what you define as an outlier. You can define outliers with a lot of methods and each value won't always be an outlier with each method. Also, an outlier is not an absurd value, sometimes outliers are just reflecting the distribution of you variable. (for example, check log-normal distribution)

Comment: To set some values as NA, you would want something like this ``mtcars %>% mutate(across(everything(), function(x) ifelse(conditition, NA, x)))``

Comment: @user438383 how would you define this `conditition`? Would I create a variable before? how would you make this more clearly?

Comment: @wesleysc352 this post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951732/r-use-dplyr-to-filter-each-column-based-on-each-columns-quantiles

Comment: This should not be re-opened until the OP has added code that at least attempts to perform the action they want that we can debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `apply`, `quantile`, and `dplyr::na_if`, you can do:

```
df[-1] <- apply(df[-1], 2, as.numeric)
df[-1] <- apply(df[-1], 2,
                 function(x) na_if(x,x[which(x < quantile(x,probs=c(0.05)))]))
df[-1] <- apply(df[-1], 2,
                 function(x) na_if(x,x[which(x > quantile(x,probs=c(0.95),na.rm=T))]))
df

   st        PH        OD        COD          N
1   A  7.300000 1.2630109  1.1123596 0.29584292
2   B 12.698759 5.6706461  4.8417483 0.09695843
3   C  9.613564 1.7062774  7.9522665 0.10267215
4   D  9.693461 7.0755602         NA 0.30249465
5   A 11.203150 5.4447561  3.1332711 0.42117211
6   B  9.288552 4.1690681         NA 0.12290062
7   C  4.207333 6.7176531 10.4907388 0.08563414
8   D 10.985939 2.3520690  8.4684368 0.14228479
9   A  8.206799 7.8267643  4.4642424 0.21120096
10  B        NA        NA  1.4883585         NA
11  C  3.971088 8.5006683  6.3152087 0.31983513
12  D  4.821069 3.8710822  8.6692842 0.34931733
13  A        NA 0.9789229 10.5375621 0.11192938
14  B  7.546888        NA  1.5840136 0.42668172
15  C  4.689617 8.7176568  7.4747099         NA
16  D  9.730568 1.1347636  4.6798102 0.21574411
17  A 12.063813 6.8625491  0.5594976 0.23198410
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
# lq = lower quantile
# uq = upper quantile
rm_outlier <- function(x, lq=5/100, uq=95/100) {
qnts = quantile(x, probs=c(lq, uq))
ifelse(x < qnts[1] | x > qnts[2], NA, x)
}
```

```r
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df[, -1], rm_outlier))
          PH        OD        COD          N
1   7.300000 1.2630109  1.1123596 0.29584292
2  12.698759 5.6706461  4.8417483 0.09695843
3   9.613564 1.7062774  7.9522665 0.10267215
4   9.693461 7.0755602         NA 0.30249465
5  11.203150 5.4447561  3.1332711 0.42117211
6   9.288552 4.1690681         NA 0.12290062
7   4.207333 6.7176531 10.4907388 0.08563414
8  10.985939 2.3520690  8.4684368 0.14228479
9   8.206799 7.8267643  4.4642424 0.21120096
10        NA        NA  1.4883585         NA
11  3.971088 8.5006683  6.3152087 0.31983513
12  4.821069 3.8710822  8.6692842 0.34931733
13        NA 0.9789229 10.5375621 0.11192938
14  7.546888        NA  1.5840136 0.42668172
15  4.689617 8.7176568  7.4747099         NA
16  9.730568 1.1347636  4.6798102 0.21574411
17 12.063813 6.8625491  0.5594976 0.23198410
```

To overwrite numeric columns while keeping non-numeric ones intact, we can do this:

```r
df[, -1] = lapply(df[, -1], rm_outlier)
df
   st        PH        OD        COD          N
1   A  7.300000 1.2630109  1.1123596 0.29584292
2   B 12.698759 5.6706461  4.8417483 0.09695843
3   C  9.613564 1.7062774  7.9522665 0.10267215
4   D  9.693461 7.0755602         NA 0.30249465
5   A 11.203150 5.4447561  3.1332711 0.42117211
6   B  9.288552 4.1690681         NA 0.12290062
7   C  4.207333 6.7176531 10.4907388 0.08563414
8   D 10.985939 2.3520690  8.4684368 0.14228479
9   A  8.206799 7.8267643  4.4642424 0.21120096
10  B        NA        NA  1.4883585         NA
11  C  3.971088 8.5006683  6.3152087 0.31983513
12  D  4.821069 3.8710822  8.6692842 0.34931733
13  A        NA 0.9789229 10.5375621 0.11192938
14  B  7.546888        NA  1.5840136 0.42668172
15  C  4.689617 8.7176568  7.4747099         NA
16  D  9.730568 1.1347636  4.6798102 0.21574411
17  A 12.063813 6.8625491  0.5594976 0.23198410
```

Comment: hello, i was surprised and glad the question was broached again. I have tested your code, but the column with `st` data is gone. how to solve? your code is shorter.

Comment: Because `st` is a character vector and does not need to touched. Now`st` remains in the df, I updated my answer.